# Compare values of two hash tables in loop

Tags: c#, hashtable

I have two hash tables. I want to compare values of both the hash tables based on the key. I want to do this in loop and if match is found is want to perform string building operation. But the problem is I dont know any mechanism to compare them in loop. Please guide me...
Following are my hash tables to be compared

```
       HashTable OldTable= new HashTable();

        OldTable.Add("Date of Event", OCEFData.EventDate);
            OldTable.Add("Angina Status", OCEFData.AnginaStatusValue);
            OldTable.Add("Please indicate the body system involved (tick all that apply)",strBodySystem.ToString());
            OldTable.Add("If Unstable Angina, define Braunswald Classification", OCEFData.UnstableAnginaValue);
            OldTable.Add("If Stable Angina", OCEFData.StableAnginaValue);
            OldTable.Add("Details of method of Documentation of Angina", OCEFData.AnginaDocDetails);
            OldTable.Add("INFORM TO SPONSOR", (OCEFData.IsInformed)?"Yes":"No");
            OldTable.Add("DATE OF INFORMATION TO SPONSOR ", OCEFData.SponsorDate);
            OldTable.Add("DATE OF INFORMATION TO INSTITUTIONAL ETHICS COMMITTEE", OCEFData.EthicsCommitteeDate);
            OldTable.Add("DATE OF INFORMATION TO LICENSING AUTHORITY", OCEFData.LicensingAuthority);



       HashTable NewTable= new HashTable();

       NewTable.Add("Date of Event", OCEFData.EventDate);
        NewTable.Add("Angina Status", OCEFData.AnginaStatusValue);
        NewTable.Add("Please indicate the body system involved (tick all that apply)", strBodySystem.ToString());
        NewTable.Add("If Unstable Angina, define Braunswald Classification", OCEFData.UnstableAnginaValue);
        NewTable.Add("If Stable Angina", OCEFData.StableAnginaValue);
        NewTable.Add("Details of method of Documentation of Angina", OCEFData.AnginaDocDetails);
        NewTable.Add("INFORM TO SPONSOR", (OCEFData.IsInformed)?"Yes":"No");
        NewTable.Add("DATE OF INFORMATION TO SPONSOR ", OCEFData.SponsorDate);
        NewTable.Add("DATE OF INFORMATION TO INSTITUTIONAL ETHICS COMMITTEE", OCEFData.EthicsCommitteeDate);
        NewTable.Add("DATE OF INFORMATION TO LICENSING AUTHORITY", OCEFData.LicensingAuthority);
```

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having difficulties with? Please post the code you have written so far and explain where you are having issues.

Comment: I am confused to start. I tried foreach loop it will not work to manipulate both the table in single iteration.

Comment: Search Google ... lot example is out there. One here for you http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Forums/Thread/83420/comparing-values-in-2-hash-tables.aspx

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. What does 'compare values based on the key' mean? And what do you do with matching values?

Comment: Looks like this is misuse of a hashtable, all should be in an other way - you should find a value by a key not  akey by a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the way you want it?

```
Hashtable OldTable = new Hashtable();
Hashtable NewTable = new Hashtable();

        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in OldTable)
        {
            if(NewTable.ContainsKey(entry.Key))
            {
                //Do something?
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Linq to intersect the keys giving you a collection of keys in both tables?

```
var combinedKeys=OldTable.Keys.Cast<string>().Intersect(NewTable.Keys.Cast<string>())
```

you can then iterate over the keys or use a Linq Select or Agregate statement to get a collection result.

**EDIT**

Because HashTable is not strongly typed, `Keys` does not give you an IEnumerable, hence the call to `Cast<string>()`  to get an `IEnumerable<string>`

If you were using a strongly typed `Dictionary<string,string>` you would not need the `Cast<string>()` part.

Comment: HashTable.Keys property has the type ICollection in System.Collections namespace. This does not have Intersect extension method (which is an extension for IEnumerable<TSource>).

Comment: @DanKodi You are correct, because HashTable doesn't have a strongly typed key, like `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.  A call to `Cast<string>()` on the `Keys` collection will solve this though.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are trying to match keys in both HashTable ... you can do like

```
 foreach (string key in oldtable.Keys)
    {
        if (newtable.Contains(key))
        {
            // do your work;
        }
        else
        {
            // do your work;         
       }
    }
```

Comment: I am trying to compare values. See the question. If values are same then I want to get the keys. Means I want only those keys from the hash tables for which values are same...

Answer (score 0):

First thing - use typed `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` rather than `Hashtable`, below is example when values are of `string` type, this would be easy changing `string` to your custom type (I believe `enum` or already string constants).

```
IDictionary<string, string> map1 = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                        {
                                            {"A", "M1-A"},
                                            {"B", "M1-B"},
                                            {"C", "M1-C"}
                                        };

IDictionary<string, string> map2 = new Dictionary<string, string>
                                        {
                                            {"A", "M2-A"},
                                            {"B", "M2-B"},
                                            {"D", "M2-D"}
                                        };
```

**.NET 3.5 and upper**: Usign LINQ `Intersect()`

```
var items = map1.Keys.Intersect(map2.Keys)
                     .Select(k => map1[k] + " / " + map2[k])
                     .ToList();
```

**<.NET 3.5**

```
IList<string> results = new List<string>();
foreach (var key in map1.Keys)
{
    if (map2.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        results.Add(map1[key] + " / " + map2[key]);
    }
}

OUTPUT:
M1-A / M2-A
M1-B / M2-B
```

Comment: The intersect solution is not optimal since you already have a dictionary and the intersect would need to put all the keys into an internal Set.